# Window not visible

Tags: c++, directx

Hello I am looking for some help, I have tried to make a window using directx and c++ and everything appears to be fine but when I run it the window isn't being displayed but NetBeans tells me that the build was successfull and tells me the program is running. Can anyone help me with my issue please?

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 
#define UNICODE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

// Variables
LPCWSTR windowTitle     = L"Window";
int     windowWidth     = 980;
int     windowHeight    = 640;
HWND    windowInstance  = NULL;
LPCWSTR windowClassName = L"WindowClass";

// Forwards
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

// Functions
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcEx;

    wcEx.cbSize        = sizeof wcEx;
    wcEx.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcEx.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    wcEx.lpszClassName = windowClassName;
    wcEx.hInstance     = hInstance;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcEx))
        return printf("Console Output: RegisterClassEx has failed!");

    windowInstance = CreateWindowEx(
                        0,
                        windowClassName,
                        windowTitle,
                        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / windowWidth,
                        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) / windowHeight,
                        windowWidth,
                        windowHeight,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        hInstance,
                        NULL
                     ); 

    if (!windowInstance)
        return printf("Console Output: There isn't an instance of 'windowInstance'. ");

    ShowWindow(windowInstance, nCmdShow);

    printf("Console Output: Program is running");

    MSG msg;

    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);

        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        } 
    }

    return DefWindowProc (hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Console:

```
 "/C/Development/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/none/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Program1'
"/C/Development/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/program1.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/none/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Program1'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d"
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/program1 build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o 
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/none/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Program1'
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/none/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Program1'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3s)
```

Run Console:

```
Console Output: RegisterClassEx has failed!
RUN FAILED (exit value 43, total time: 117ms)
```

Comment: Do you get a non-`NULL`return value from `CreateWindowEx`? What value does `nCmdShow` have?

Comment: You should check return values, your `RegisterClassEx` fails, which causes `CreateWindowEx` to also fail and return `NULL`.

Comment: Updated question with the new code and console log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to initialize your `wcEx` to 0, this means the parts that you don't set can potentially contain trash values, which can cause `RegisterClassEx` to fail.

Changing to:

```
WNDCLASSEX wcEx;
memset(&wcEx, 0, sizeof wcEx);
```

or:

```
WNDCLASSEX wcEx = {0};
```

Should fix your problem.